# Authentication in middleware no longer working after exporting middleware function in next js

Tags: next.js, middleware, next-auth

I have a middleware file in order to make a login system in my nextjs 14 project. I'm following [this guide](https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/adding-authentication) and [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBg6xA5C60s)

My file look like this

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import { authConfig } from '@/app/auth.config';

export default NextAuth(authConfig).auth;

export const config = {
    // https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#matcher
    matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|.*\\.png$).*)'],
};
```

And it's working fine!

Now...I need to change that file so I can modify the headers of the request to add some extra info and have it available throughout the project.

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import { authConfig } from '@/app/auth.config';
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export default NextAuth(authConfig).auth;

export const config = {
    // https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#matcher
    matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|.*\\.png$).*)'],
};

export function middleware(request)
{
    const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
    const query = {};

    request.nextUrl.searchParams.forEach(function(value, key)
    {
        query[key] = value;
    });

    requestHeaders.set("x-resource", request.nextUrl.pathname);
    requestHeaders.set("x-query", JSON.stringify(query));

    return NextResponse.next({
        request: {
            headers: requestHeaders,
        },
    });
}
```

The problem is that the auth part is no longer working and my *protected* folders are now *public*. Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix it?

**UPDATE 1**

I thought maybe it has to do with the fact that I'm altering the headers, but this also makes the auth to fail

```
export function middleware()
{

}
```

So just exporting a `middleware()` function with nothing inside breaks it.

**UPDATE 2**

Reading, reading and reading I stumbled upon this approach

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import { authConfig } from '@/app/auth.config';
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

const authProvider = NextAuth(authConfig).auth;

export const config = {
    // https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#matcher
    matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|.*\\.png$).*)'],
};

const middleware = function(request)
{
    const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
    const query = {};

    request.nextUrl.searchParams.forEach(function(value, key)
    {
        query[key] = value;
    });

    requestHeaders.set("x-resource", request.nextUrl.pathname.replace("/add", "").replace("/edit", ""));
    requestHeaders.set("x-query", JSON.stringify(query));

    return NextResponse.next({
        request: {
            headers: requestHeaders,
        },
    });
}

export default authProvider(middleware);
```

that kind of works, but it fails on redirect at login and logout (it perform the action, but doesn't redirect)

Comment: Why are you setting the request headers? Shouldn't you just be modifying the `headers` property instead of `request.headers`?

Comment: because I need a way to access the params and pathname in all server components

Comment: As far as I know, the params and pathname are available under the `usePathname` and `useParams` hooks. Server components **do not** have access to these properties.

Comment: It kind of does in this middleware. I'm using it that way, but then the auth part no longer works

Answer (score -1):

Next.js expect you to either `export default` middleware or export named middleware function `export function middleware` You cannot export both. This why the first code snippet doesn't work as expected.

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import { authConfig } from '@/app/auth.config';
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const config = {
    // https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#matcher
    matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|.*\\.png$).*)'],
};

export const middleware = NextAuth(authConfig).auth(function (request) {
  // `request` now has a property `auth` containing the session

  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
  const query = {};

  request.nextUrl.searchParams.forEach(function (value, key) {
    query[key] = value;
  });

  requestHeaders.set(
    "x-resource",
    request.nextUrl.pathname.replace("/add", "").replace("/edit", "")
  );
  requestHeaders.set("x-query", JSON.stringify(query));

  // Auth Logic
  const isProtected = true;
  // this can be either
  // ["/admin", "/protected", ...].includes(request.nextUrl.pathname)
  // or 
  // ["/login", "/register", ...].includes(request.nextUrl.pathname) !== true

  if (isProtected && !req.auth?.user) {
    const loginUrl = new URL("/login", request.url);
    // Add ?callbackUrl=/incoming-url to the /login URL
    loginUrl.searchParams.set("callbackUrl", request.nextUrl.pathname);
    // And redirect to the new URL
    return NextResponse.redirect(loginUrl);
  }

  return NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      headers: requestHeaders,
    },
  });
});
```

If you need to access the searchParams in your app, no need to write to the headers. every `page.js` has a param called `searchParams`

```js
// app/edit/page.js

export default function EditPage({ searchParams }) {
  const sort = searchParams.sort;

  // ...
}
```

or via `useSearchParams` in Client Components

```js
"use client";

import {useSearchParams} from "next/navigation";

export function MyComponent() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const sort = searchParams.get("sort")
}
```

Comment: this is similar to my update 2 where kind of works, but it fails on redirect at login and logout (it perform the action, but doesn't redirect). I'm using auth.config's authorize instead of `if (isProtected...` in middleware